# При ручном вводе в textarea не срабатывают скрипты

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Есть вот такая страничка

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ajax">
    <input id="upfile" type="file" name="upfile"><br>
    <textarea id="description_area"></textarea><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Load Picture</button>
</div>

<button onclick="view()">Show Pre-View</button>
<div id="view">

</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

И вот такой скрипт:

```
var file=document.getElementById("upfile"),
    form=new FormData();

function loadDoc() {
    var up_file=file.files[0];
    form.append("upfile",up_file);
    form.append("action","load_description_image");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var text=document.createTextNode('\n[img]'+this.responseText+'[/img]\n');
            document.getElementById('description_area').appendChild(text);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "start", true);
    xhttp.send(form);
}
```

Если нажимать на кнопку Load Picture, то строки добавляются. Но как только я пытаюсь вручную добавить какой-то текст и потом нажать на кнопку, он перестаёт добавляться. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = '\n[img]' + this.responseText + '[/img]\n';
document.getElementById('description_area').value = 
  document.getElementById('description_area').value + text;
```

P.S. Обратите внимание, что в `form` каждый раз добавляется файл.

Comment: Благодарю. Насчет формы не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: `form.append("upfile",up_file);` - выполняется для того же самого `form` при повторных нажатиях кнoпки.